# How to start content div below fixed header without giving margin?

Tags: html, css, header, css-position

Div with id header is fixed but the div with the id content is going behind the header div. What can I do if I want to fix this issue without adding margin-top to the content div?

I tried adding margin-top but it occurs the problem with other elements in responsive view.

**My code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>

    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #header {
            color: white;
            font-size: 18px;
            background-color: black;
            text-align: center;
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            top: 0;
            opacity: 0.8;
        }

        #header div {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            border: 1px solid grey;
        }

        #content {
            background-color: orange;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div>
            <p>This is header</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add `padding-top` on `body`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
  body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #header {
            color: white;
            font-size: 18px;
            background-color: black;
            text-align: center;
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            top: 0;
            opacity: 0.8;
        }

        #header div {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            border: 1px solid grey;
        }

        #content {
            background-color: orange;
        }

        #a { 
            content: "";
            display: block;
            height: 40px;
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div>
            <p>This is header</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  <div id="a"></div>
    <div id="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
 body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #header {
            color: white;
            font-size: 18px;
            background-color: black;
            text-align: center;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 1;
            width: 100%;
            top: 0;
            opacity: 0.8;
        }

        #header div {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            border: 1px solid grey;
        }

        #content {
            background-color: orange;
            position: relative;
            top: 55px;
            padding-top:10px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div>
            <p>This is header</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Expedita facere iusto vel aperiam, maiores dignissimos magni quam, laudantium officiis cupiditate libero soluta eum consequuntur dolores blanditiis, in recusandae sequi incidunt.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```